# how do I know if a file exists in the current directory tree

Tags: php, security

I want to check if a file path is in current directory tree.

Suppose the parameter is given as `js/script.js`. My working directory (WD) is `/home/user1/public_html/site`

Now for current WD if someone supplies `js/script.js` I can simply check it by appending to the WD. It works for such normal path. But if anyone (may be an attacker) wants to pass `../../../../etc/password` it'd be a problem.

I know it can be suppressed by removing the `..` characters using some RegEx. And that will solve it for sure. But I want to know how can I create some sort of `chroot`ed environment sot that whatever path/to/script is passed it will be searched under WD?

Edit:
I am aware of http://php.net/chroot. it requires your app to run with root privileges.

Comment: From php 5.3.0 it is possible to set the open_basedir from your PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

```
$chroot = '/var/www/site/userdata/';
$basefolder = '/var/www/site/userdata/mine/';

$param = '../../../../etc/password';
$fullpath = realpath($basefolder . $param);

if (strpos($fullpath, $chroot) !== 0) {
  // GOTCHA
}
```